# geolocation does not work ionic 3 - android

Tags: android, angular, typescript, geolocation, ionic3

I have problem with plugin

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

The geolocation does not work ionic 3 - ANDROID but in web browser from my computer its normal for me, this is my code:

```
export class TestPage {
  state: string = "";

  constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation,
    public platform: Platform) {

      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
          // resp.coords.latitude
          // resp.coords.longitude
          this.state+="-"+resp.coords.latitude;
         }).catch((error) => {
          this.state+="-"+error.message;
        });
      });

  }
}
```

[image]

The result it´s above, I need your help, whats is the wrong??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592356/ionic-3-geolocation-not-working-when-gps-is-disabled .  Please answer above question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below `CLI` with `Android device`.It won't work with `--livereload`.

**Reason:** Google regards `localhost` as secure, but others as not.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

You can read more about this issue [**here**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-geolocation-only-secure-origins-are-allowed-error/61333) and [**here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ng-cordova/issues/1413).

Comment: so only its work on prod, but and I want to make my test on localhost, there is anyway?

Comment: `--prod --device` this is a debug version and you can do debugging on the device using the USB port.