# Ionic 3 geolocation not working when GPS is disabled

Tags: javascript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic4

I have ionic native geolocation plugin installed

```
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.15.0"
```

I have also tried "4.6.0" and "4.20.0". It is working absolutely fine when I keep my GPS enabled before going to that page. But when GPS is not enabled, It won't ask me to turn it ON, gives an error on console and carry undefined coordinates with it.

I wrote the method of getCurrentPosition in constructor/ionViewDidLoad. So even user enable it on that page, the method does not invoke and the coordinates remain undefined.

Following is code

```
this.geolocation
  .getCurrentPosition()
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
    this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting location", error);
  });
```

I don't know if I'll have to give manual permissions or what?? I did the same before a couple of months before and everything was fine. First time I am facing this kind of issue. Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

you should manually ask permission and request the user to enable location. You can do this with the Diagnostic plugin (@ionic-native/diagnostic). You should use the following methods:

```js
diagnostic.isLocationEnabled()
diagnostic.isLocationAvailable()
diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization()
```

If you want to update location after permission is granted you you can use this method:

```js
diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler()
```

You can pass a callback here check if location is enabled and available de what you need.

Comment: Where should I write this code? Either in the constructor or in ionViewDidEnter or somewhere else?

Comment: That depends on the functionality you desire for your application. Keep in mind the lifecycle events (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/) to get the behaviour you want. Constructor is called when the component is instantiated, ionViewDidEnter is called each time the view becomes active.

This depends on how critical it is for your app to get position. Beware that you may not get it if the user doesn't allow the app to get the position. So you should consider that case. I would check each time on enter and ask for permissions if not granted.

Comment: @NicolásLonghi : sir its woking in one case:                                                                    Suppose i jump to GPS location setting now i am not enable the GPS and click mobile back button its not wokring in such condition,how to check again because user GPS is off  now how to manage this case sir?

Comment: When the app goes back into foreground, don't assume you have location available. As stated above, you can use diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler() to listen to changes, or you could ask again if permissions have been granted.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Diagnostics plugin from here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/diagnostic/, then check if location is enabled with `diagnostics.isLocationAvailable()`, if not, prompt the user to enable it from the device settings screen using `diagnostics.switchToLocationSettings()`.

Comment: sir its woking in one case: Suppose i jump to GPS location setting now i am not enable the GPS and click mobile back button its not wokring in such condition,how to check again because user GPS is off now how to manage this case sir

Comment: In the modal where you prompt the user to open location settings, add another button to allow the user call the method that re-initializes geolocation.

Comment: but why need to click button for re-initializes i have re-initializes without click any button?